# Is it possible to have classic asp.net dynamically load subtypes of declared webcontrols

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, web-controls, multi-tenant

I want to be able to declaratively specify the webcontrols of any given page in the standard way, *but* have the runtime not necessarily new up instances of the types I specified, but rather for instance check against web.config whether a different webcontrol (which would inherit from the specified one)  should be used instead.

for instance I could have a webcontrol in the path /templates/controls/default/PersonSelector.ascx and another one in the path /templates/controls/CUSTOMER_A/PersonSelector.ascx (inheriting from the first)

so if my config indicated that I preferred to load controls from the CUSTOMER_A folder where available, and since it would be available in this case, the *actual* markup which was used for the page would come from .../CUSTOMER_A/PersonSelector.ascx. All code which compile-time assumed that it was in fact an instance of ../default/PersonSelector.ascx would still work since it is actually a subclass.

This would afaik be a major benefit to our site which is a multitenant site in which 99.5% of the generated html is identical across all our customers (except for skinning, naturally) but *some* of the customers wants different headers/footers/selection-logic etc. So far all the differences are handled by bloating the controls and if/else-ing all over the place.

I realize that asp.net is probably not the weapon of choice for doing this kind of thing, but it's the one we've got, and the codebase is large enough that a rewrite would be a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can load user controls dynamically using the [`LoadControl` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.loadcontrol.aspx). Provided that you have `Control1` and a `Control2`, where `Control2` inherits from `Control1`, you could do this in a page:

```
//Obtain control name in the format "~/pathFromApplicationRoot/ControlName.ascx"
string controlName = MethodThatDecidesTheControlNameToLoad();
//Load control
var userControl = (Control1)this.LoadControl(controlName);
//Add it to page
AControlSuchAsAPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(userControl);
```

**Edit:**
In order to be able to specify your user controls declaratively in markup I guess you could make the user control replace its own content with the tenant specific control if the config told it to override.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can manually do this, what I am after though is whether I can override the default behaviour of asp.net such that it doesn't actually necessarily load the controls as specified in the aspx/ascx markup but rather childs of those controls, probably by either replacing PageHandlerFactory or exchanging the loading mechanism somehow.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your point of wanting to do this automatically in the pipeline. I'm not sure on how to hook in to the pipeline for user controls, but I updated my answer with the first idea that popped into my head.